# Is there an official name for a linear system with some zero outputs?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear system, I have some zero outputs, i.e., 
$\begin{bmatrix}A& B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are matrices.

Is there a name for these kind of equations (like overspecified, underspecified, weird, etc.), which I can use to google out more information. Thank you.

Comment: When all of the outputs are zero, it's a "homogeneous" system.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so... Semihomogenous?